# Pyspark - Convert to Timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark version : 2.1

I'm trying to convert a string datetime column to utc timestamp with the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`

I first start by changing the format of the string column to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`
and then convert it to timestamp type. Later I would convert the timestamp to UTC using `to_utc_timestamp` function.

```py
df.select(
    f.to_timestamp(
        f.date_format(f.col("time"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    )
).show(5, False)
```

The `date_format` works fine by giving me the correct format. But, when I do `to_timestamp` on top of that result, the format changes to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, when it should instead be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Why does this happen?

Could someone tell me how I could retain the format given by date_format? What should I do?

Comment: Timestamp format is, internally, an INT : the number of secondes from ~1970 ... It does not have any format, the representation that you see `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is just the human readable transformation of that number of seconds. If you want another format in your output, you need to convert it to string - it won't be a timestamp anymore

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function to_timestamp returns a string to a timestamp, with the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

The second argument is used to define the format of the DateTime in the string you are trying to parse.

You can see a couple of examples in the [official documentation](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/pyspark-to_timestamp-convert-string-to-timestamp-type/).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The code should be like this, just look at the single 'd' part here, and this is tricky in many cases.

```
data= data.withColumn('date', to_timestamp(col('date'), 'yyyy/MM/d'))
```

[image]

Comment: my `to_timestamp` return 04:00:00 even when I set    `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")`. Do you know how to solve this issue?